# How do you divide 2 algebraic expressions, where their exponents aren't all integers?

Tags: polynomials

Examples include $\frac{3x^3+2}{\sqrt[3]{x}+2x^3}$

Answer (score 2):

Simple, long division:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                    3/2  \\[-3pt]
2x^3+x^{1/3} \enclose{longdiv}{3x^3+0x^{1/3}+2} \\[-3pt]
         \underline{3x^3+\frac32x^{1/3}\ \ \ \downarrow}\\[-3pt]
                    -\frac32x^{1/3}+2  \\
\end{array}
$$

Thus,

$$\frac{3x^3+2}{2x^3+x^{1/3}}=\frac32-\underbrace{\frac{\frac32x^{1/3}-2}{2x^3+x^{1/3}}}_{\text{Remainder}}$$

And this is as far as you would usually have to simplify.  If you proceed to do this indefinitely, you get a Laurent series, which would be of interest if you were in complex analysis.